# How to understand havex malware encoder with some code?

Tags: encryption, reverse-engineering, malware, ida

I'm analyzing [havex](https://www.cyber.nj.gov/threat-profiles/ics-malware-variants/havex), a malware. It generate a dll file and I use ida to reverse it. I found some code, and cann't understand.

```
while ( *(_DWORD *)(a1 + 32) < 8 )
{
  v300 = *(_DWORD **)a1;
  if ( !*(_DWORD *)(*(_DWORD *)a1 + 4) )
    goto LABEL_367;
  v301 = *(unsigned __int8 *)*v300;
  v302 = *(_DWORD *)(a1 + 28);
  *(_DWORD *)(a1 + 32) += 8;
  *(_DWORD *)(a1 + 28) = v301 | (v302 << 8);
  ++*v300;
  --*(_DWORD *)(*(_DWORD *)a1 + 4);
  if ( !++*(_DWORD *)(*(_DWORD *)a1 + 8) )
    ++*(_DWORD *)(*(_DWORD *)a1 + 12);
}
v303 = *(_DWORD *)(a1 + 32);
v304 = *(_DWORD *)(a1 + 28) >> (v303 - 8);
*(_DWORD *)(a1 + 32) = v303 - 8;
*(_DWORD *)(a1 + 3164) = (unsigned __int8)v304 | (*(_DWORD *)(a1 + 3164) << 8);
*(_DWORD *)(a1 + 4) = 1;
v305 = 4;
goto LABEL_34;
```

I think it's a check code, but I'm not sure. Is it a decryption or some other check code?

Answer (score 2):

Look, this is simply not enough data to properly reverse this. You should do some work with your code:

- Change `a1` to structure (or an array, but that's unlikely)
- Change the types of variables to remove excessive typecasting
- Analyse code behaviour dynamically, not only statically

That said, this is probably not decryption. Encryption/decryption is build mostly on xor, and the only data-changing operations here are addition, bit shifts and bitwise or. If it's decryption - than that's one weird encryption scheme.

I have a feeling that this might be some kind of hashing operation, you can totally implement them with or and bitshifts, but it's too much work to analyze Interactive DisAssembler code by looking at non-interactive text ;)